# How do I disable focus follows mouse?

Tags: gsettings

I have enabled the following.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'mouse'
```

Now how can I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset any `gsettings` key to its default value by `gsettings reset ...`.
So in this case run

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode
```

Alternatively, run

```
gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode
```

to get the all possible permitted values and set the one you like by

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode <your-choice>
```